# need some advice in threading

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I have an app which can download images from a website,

it runs perfectly, but there is only one thing that annoys me, it is CPU intensive.

here is my code, could anyone give any advice how to handle this?

thank you so much!

Task.java

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

private String url;
private int server;

public Task(String url, int server) {
    this.url = url;
    this.server = server;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    android.os.Process
            .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_LESS_FAVORABLE);
    int page = 1;
    String r1 = "";
    if (server == 1) {
        r1 = getRaw(url);
    } else if (server == 2) {
        url = url + "page/";
        r1 = getRaw(url + page);
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String subs = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    List<String> a1 = getPackage(r1, server);
    String t1 = getImageLink(r1, server);
    String loc = DownloadXML.UNDUH + File.separator + a1.get(0)
            + File.separator + a1.get(1) + ' ' + a1.get(2);
    File f1 = new File(loc);
    if (!f1.exists())
        f1.mkdirs();
    getImage(loc, t1, page);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    page++;
    if (server == 1) {
        while (true) {
            r1 = getRaw(subs + page);
            t1 = getImageLink(r1, server);
            if (t1 != null) {
                getImage(loc, t1, page);
                page++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return;
    } else if (server == 2) {
        int maxPage = Integer.parseInt(a1.get(3));
        while (page <= maxPage) {
            r1 = getRaw(subs + page);
            t1 = getImageLink(r1, server);
            if (t1 != null) {
                getImage(loc, t1, page);
                page++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

}

private String getRaw(String link) {
    String raw = null;
    try {
        URL myUrl = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            raw += line;
        }
        is.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return raw;
}

private List<String> getPackage(String raw, int server) {
    List<String> pack = new ArrayList<String>();
    switch (server) {
    case 1:
        Pattern pattern = Pattern
                .compile("<span class=\"visible-desktop visible-tablet.+?</span>.+?<span class=\"visible-desktop visible-tablet.+?</span>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(raw);
        String b = null;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            b = matcher.group();
            if (b != null) {
                String[] t = b.split("<[^>]*>");
                for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
                    if (!t[i].isEmpty()) {
                        pack.add(t[i].trim());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern
                .compile("<div class=\"topbar_left\">.+?</a>.+?</a>");
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(raw);
        Pattern pPage = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"tbtitle dropdown_parent dropdown_right\"><div class=\"text\">[0-9]+ </div>");
        Matcher mPage = pPage.matcher(raw);
        while (matcher1.find()) {
            String s = matcher1.group().trim();
            s = s.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
            String[] temp = s.split("[:]+");
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                if (temp[i] != null)
                    if (i == 1) {
                        pack.add(temp[i].replaceAll("[a-zA-z]+", "").trim());
                    } else if (i == 2) {
                        pack.add("- "
                                + temp[i].trim().replaceAll(
                                        "[^a-zA-z0-9]+", "_"));
                    } else {
                        pack.add(temp[i].trim());
                    }
            }
        }
        while (mPage.find()) {
            pack.add(mPage.group().replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "").trim());
        }
        break;
    }
    return pack;
}

private String getImageLink(String raws, int server) {
    /*
     * Return image link
     */
    switch (server) {
    case 1:
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://img.+(jpg|png)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(raws);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern
                .compile("http://manga.redhawkscans.com/content/comics/.+?(jpg|png)");
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(raws);
        while (matcher1.find()) {
            if (matcher1.group().contains("thumb")) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return matcher1.group();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return null;
}

private void getImage(String loc, String link, int page) {
    /*
     * Get image and save it
     */
    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestProperty(
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");
        String form = link.substring(link.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        String p = "0";
        if (page < 10) {
            p += Integer.toString(page);
        } else {
            p = Integer.toString(page);
        }
        File f = new File(loc, p + '.' + form);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        if (form == "jpg") {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        } else {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
   }
```

and in another class, I just call new Thread(new Task(link,server)).start() to start the threading.

Comment: From a quick look at your code:
- Use precompiled static pattern fields: private static final Pattern PATTERN_A = Pattern.compile("http://img.+(jpg|png)");
- in getRaw you need to add new line charachter: raw += line + "\n";

Comment: The main cpu intensive operations are decoding input stream into a Bitmap and then recompressing it into a file. If you could write directly to a file I guess you problem would go away (in getImage)

Comment: @Rahim thanks for your suggestions, I will try to reduce Regex usage though

Answer (score 0):

1. A lot of code that uses RegExps working with large strings (web pages?)
2. converting images on the fly.
3. new URLConnection on every request.

Try to:

1. Test your RegExp's performance and work with it. Short and too complicated RegExps like [abc] is very slow on large strings.
2. Do you really need to recompress your bitmaps. May be it's better to store original stream to file rather than recompress it?
3. Create Connection pool or shared connection to increase connection time and minimize unneeded initializations.

Also you can try minimize thread priority to BACKGROUND:
android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

Comment: yeah I will try to reduce RegExps usage, I retrieve all data from website.. and how to create connection pool? thanks for your suggestions!